# JavaScript get closest class

Tags: javascript

I want to show reply forms in my comment section based on comment reply button that has been clicked but currently it shows forms of all comments instead of specific comment. **The question is**

How do I get closest form in order to just show one form at the time?

## Code

```
// this button exist in all comments with same class
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary text-light reply">Reply</button>

//reply form DIV
<div class="blog-form mt-6 replyComment" style="display:none">// form here</div>

// New comment form DIV
<div class="blog-form mt-6 originalComment"> //form here </div>


$('.reply').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.replyComment').show();
  $('.originalComment').hide();
});
```

## Update

Full commenting code

```
<div class="blog-comments mt-4">
    @include('errors.errors')

    @if(isset($post))
        @forelse($post->comments as $comment)
            <div class="comments-1 w-100">
                <div class="comments-photo">
                    @if(!empty($comment->user->avatar))
                    <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{url('images/idus')}}/{{ $comment->user->avatar }}" alt="{{$comment->user->name}}">
                    @else
                    <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{asset('img/red_avatar.jpg')}}" alt="{{$comment->user->name}}">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="comments-info">
                    <h6> {{$comment->user->name}} <span>{{$comment->created_at->format('M d, Y')}}</span></h6>
                    <div class="port-post-social float-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary text-light reply">Reply</button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="mt-1">{!! $comment->comment !!}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blog-form mt-6 replyComment" style="display:none">
                <h4 class="mb-3">Post a Reply</h4>

                <form method="post" action="{{ route('reply.add') }}">
                    @csrf
                <div class="gray-form row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}" />
                        @if(isset($post))
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
                        @elseif(isset($product))
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}" />
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="button red" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            @forelse($comment->replies as $reply)
            <div class="comments-1 comments-2 w-100">
                <div class="comments-photo">
                    @if(!empty($reply->user->avatar))
                    <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{url('images/idus')}}/{{ $reply->user->avatar }}" alt="{{$reply->user->name}}">
                    @else
                    <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{asset('img/red_avatar.jpg')}}" alt="{{$reply->user->name}}">
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="comments-info p-3 bg-light">
                    <h6> {{$reply->user->name}} <span>{{$reply->created_at->format('M d, Y')}}</span></h6>
                    <div class="port-post-social float-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary text-light reply">Reply</button>
                    </div>
                    <p class="mt-1">{!! $reply->comment !!}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blog-form mt-6 replyComment" style="display:none">
                <h4 class="mb-3">Post a Reply</h4>

                <form method="post" action="{{ route('reply.add') }}">
                    @csrf
                <div class="gray-form row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ $reply->id }}" />
                        @if(isset($post))
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
                        @elseif(isset($product))
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}" />
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="button red" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>


                @forelse($reply->replies as $reply2)
                <div class="comments-1 comments-2 ml-5 w-100">
                    <div class="comments-photo">
                        @if(!empty($reply->user->avatar))
                        <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{url('images/idus')}}/{{ $reply2->user->avatar }}" alt="{{$reply2->user->name}}">
                        @else
                        <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{asset('img/red_avatar.jpg')}}" alt="{{$reply2->user->name}}">
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="comments-info bg-light p-3">
                        <h6> {{$reply2->user->name}} <span>{{$reply2->created_at->format('M d, Y')}}</span></h6>
                        <p class="mt-1">{!! $reply2->comment !!}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @empty
                @endforelse
            @empty
            @endforelse
        @empty
        <h3>Be the first to leave a comment.</h3>
        @endforelse
    @else
    {{-- reserved for products reviews --}}
    @endif
</div>
<div class="blog-form mt-6 originalComment">
    <h4 class="mb-3">Post a Comment</h4>

    <form method="post" action="{{ route('comments.store') }}">
        @csrf
    <div class="gray-form row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @if(isset($post))
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
            @elseif(isset($product))
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}" />
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" name="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="button red" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Minimizing the forms above for better understanding

#### Structure

```
<comments>
  -reply button
  <reply form></reply form>

  <comment reply>
       -reply button
       <reply form></reply form>


       <comment reply replies>
       <comment reply replies>
   </comment reply>

</comments>

<comment form>
</comment form>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of your code showing the form?

Comment: @CarlEdwards updated

Comment: Can you please include the real HTML markup, or at least a portion of the forms, etc, instead of comments?

Comment: @TylerRoper I will but it's extremely long you'll be confused

Comment: @TylerRoper updated

Comment: @TylerRoper it's fine bro i placed the forms back please check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `<div>` that you want to show is the element that follows the button's `comments-1` ancestor.

Given this, I would use `.closest('.comments-1')` to select the ancestor, and `.next('.replyComment')` to select the element that follows.

```
$('.reply').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".replyComment, .originalComment").hide();
  $(this).closest('.comments-1').next('.replyComment').show();
});
```

Comment: Ok it shows the forms now regarding to clicked reply button but just in case user has clicked the wrong reply button is it possible to close (hide) it when user clicks on another reply button? currently it keeps all open(show) when i click several reply buttons

Comment: @mafortis Edited. You can hide all of the `.replyComment` elements, then show only the relevant one.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on whether there is a form above the button (then it won't work):

```js
function opens(arg) {
var closest = document.getElementsByClassName("blog-form");
closest[arg].style.display = "block";
for(var i = 1; i < closest.length; i++) {
    if(i != arg) {
    closest[i].style.display = "none";
    }      
}
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "opens(0)">Reply</button>
<form class = "blog-form" style = "display: none">
<input>
</form>
<form class = "blog-form" style = "display: none">

<input>
</form>
<button onclick = "opens(1)">Another Reply</button>
```

In order for this to work, I'm manipulating the CSS `display` property.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: closest[0].show is not a function` Also updated my question

Comment: You could use `display` instead of show? (I don't use jquery, I only used show because you had it in your question)

Comment: please provide your solution regardless of what i currently have it might work, obviously what i have now doesn't work that's why i shared question here :)

Comment: I posted my new solution

Comment: this shows reply form but there is 2 issues with it `1` it only shows 1 form regardless of what reply button i clicked `2` it shows it at the top of all comments before shows below each comment i clicked (that's the right way)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know there were multiple buttons, for the second issue you could place the form how ever you want it, and for the issue you could pass an arguement through the function

Comment: it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Comment: and if i put it in my function it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: opens is not defined`